# Network issue on Apache Spark deployment

Tags: java, apache-spark, ubuntu-server

So far I have been using Spark "embedded" in my app. Now, I'd like to run it on a dedicated server.

I am that far:

- fresh ubuntu 16, server name is micha / ip 10.0.100.120, installed scala 2.10, installed Spark 1.6.2, recompiled
- Pi test works
- UI on port 8080 works

Log says:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/conf/:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip micha --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/07/10 13:03:55 INFO Master: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/07/10 13:03:55 WARN Utils: Your hostname, micha resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.100.120 instead (on interface eno1)
16/07/10 13:03:55 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
16/07/10 13:03:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/10 13:03:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/07/10 13:03:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/07/10 13:03:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://micha:7077
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Master: Running Spark version 1.6.2
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO MasterWebUI: Started MasterWebUI at http://10.0.100.120:8080
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@micha:6066
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
16/07/10 13:03:56 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

In my app, i changed the config to:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:6066");
```

(also tried **7077**)

On the client:

```
16-07-10 13:22:58:300 INFO org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16-07-10 13:22:58:300 DEBUG org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16-07-10 13:22:58:300 DEBUG org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server@3eb292cd
16-07-10 13:22:58:301 INFO org.apache.spark.util.Utils - Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16-07-10 13:22:58:306 INFO org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI - Started SparkUI at http://10.0.100.100:4040
16-07-10 13:22:58:621 INFO org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint - Connecting to master spark://10.0.100.120:6066...
16-07-10 13:22:58:648 DEBUG org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory - Creating new connection to /10.0.100.120:6066
16-07-10 13:22:58:689 DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
16-07-10 13:22:58:714 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint - Failed to connect to master 10.0.100.120:6066
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.100.120:6066
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
```

and if I try to telnet:

```
$ telnet 10.0.100.120 6066
Trying 10.0.100.120...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.100.120: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

$ telnet 10.0.100.120 7077
Trying 10.0.100.120...
telnet: connect to address 10.0.100.120: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

On the server, I checked with netstat:

```
jgp@micha:/opt/apache-spark$ netstat -a | grep 6066
tcp6       0      0 micha.nc.rr.com:6066    [::]:*                  LISTEN     
jgp@micha:/opt/apache-spark$ netstat -a | grep 7077
tcp6       0      0 micha.nc.rr.com:7077    [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

If I interpret this, it looks like it listens in IP v6 and not v4...

**Update #1:**

I set:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=10.0.100.120
```

I still have the warning in the log:

```
16/07/10 14:10:13 WARN Utils: Your hostname, micha resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.100.120 instead (on interface eno1)
16/07/10 14:10:13 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
```

and still connection refused...

**Update #2:**

There was this weird line in /etc/hosts of the system:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      micha.nc.rr.com micha
```

I have commented it out and now I have the following in Spark's logfile:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/conf/:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/apache-spark-1.6.2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip micha --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/07/10 22:11:54 INFO Master: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/07/10 22:11:54 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/10 22:11:54 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/07/10 22:11:54 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/07/10 22:11:54 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7077. Attempting port 7078.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7078. Attempting port 7079.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7079. Attempting port 7080.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7080. Attempting port 7081.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7081. Attempting port 7082.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7082. Attempting port 7083.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7083. Attempting port 7084.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7084. Attempting port 7085.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7085. Attempting port 7086.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7086. Attempting port 7087.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7087. Attempting port 7088.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7088. Attempting port 7089.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7089. Attempting port 7090.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7090. Attempting port 7091.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7091. Attempting port 7092.
16/07/10 22:11:55 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkMaster' could not bind on port 7092. Attempting port 7093.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkMaster' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'sparkMaster' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: At least this seems odd `micha resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1` since a loopback address normally points to `127.0.0.1` but I guess that there are something wrong with this loopback configuration on your system. This is just a thing that you should take into consideration. Don't know how to resolve your problem though. Upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks Jorge - I set 2 env variables (see update) but it still does not care.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure `spark-env.sh` file in your Spark Server. Add `SPARK_MASTER_IP` to `spark-env.sh`.

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=10.0.100.120
```

And for connecting to master from your remote application use `7077` port. `6066` is for REST API.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:7077");
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my /etc/hosts was pointing the name of the host to 127.0.1.1 instead of the real IP, so for some reasons the services listened to 127.0.1.1, not 10.0.100.120